# xamarin monotouch Read sent SMS in iphone?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin

i am developing app using xamarin iOS in my app i have to read sent items(sms) details in iphone. I can read or access the messages or not.Please help me to read sms details using xamarin

Comment: Totally unclear what you asking. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not expose any public APIs that will allow you to access the native SMS system.  You can display a Message composer view to the User, who can send a message, but that is it.